# How to fix 'Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1' on my flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter

so I've been trying to run my flutter project on VSCode, however, everytime I attempt to run my code through android studio it spits out the error 'Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1'

This is very peculiar to me as I've not encountered this issue before and it seems to output the same error even when I try to run an empty flutter project.

Here is the console log:[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee8lo.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

In pubspec. Yaml change the version of webview_flutter to any and run pub get again. It should fetch the relevant version automatically

Comment: I tried that just now, and it returned the same error. Perhaps it's something else?

Comment: Please try a flutter clean then flutter pub get